# Price Update only

Tags: magento2

is it possible to upload the only price of the product via csv file?
I tried to upload the new price with the sku number of the product and update price but it showing me several errors like for some product name should be in the list and for some product products item code should be there.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to update the price only two columns **SKU** and **price**. But you have added SKU in CSV is compulsory to available for the product if it's not then Magento creates new products then it's showing several errors like product name does not exist etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Export the Catalog csv from the export Feature and update the prices in that same file and Reimport. Do not remove any columns from the sheet.

This should work without any errors